# Error in installing NVIDIA driver on manjaro linux

Tags: drivers, nvidia, manjaro, graphics

I have hybrid (NVIDIA + Intel) graphics card laptop. I can't seem to install the nvidia proprietary driver. Here is the output of `sudo mhwd -a pci nonfree 0300` command.

```
[iht@iht-pc ~]$ sudo mhwd -a pci nonfree 0300
> Using config 'video-hybrid-intel-nvidia-430xx-bumblebee' for device: 0000:00:02.0 (0300:8086:5916) Display controller Intel Corporation 
> Installing video-hybrid-intel-nvidia-430xx-bumblebee...
Sourcing /etc/mhwd-x86_64.conf
Has lib32 support: true
Sourcing /var/lib/mhwd/db/pci/graphic_drivers/hybrid-intel-nvidia-430xx-bumblebee/MHWDCONFIG
Processing classid: 0300
Sourcing /var/lib/mhwd/scripts/include/0300
:: Synchronizing package databases...
error: target not found: nvidia-430xx-utils
warning: downgrading package xf86-video-intel (1:2.99.917+899+gf66d3954-1 => 1:2.99.917+847+g25c9a2fc-1)
error: target not found: lib32-nvidia-430xx-utils
error: target not found: linux316-nvidia-430xx
error: target not found: linux54-nvidia-430xx
error: target not found: linux54-bbswitch
 core is up to date
 extra is up to date
 community is up to date
 multilib is up to date
Error: pacman failed!
Error: script failed!
```